# video Duration Limit is not working in iOS 14 and image editing also not working in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

[Plugin Url](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/)

this below code doesn't allow durationLimit filter.

Image Picker version: 4.6.0
React Native version: 0.66.3
Platform: iOS
Development Operating System: MacOS
Dev tools: Xcode, iOS

```
mediaType: 'video',
videoQuality: 'medium',
durationLimit: 30,
allowsEditing: true,
};
launchImageLibrary(options, async res => {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

durationLimit only works for videos taken from camera

**For video Duration Limit in iOS**

```
ImagePicker.launchCamera(    
{
    mediaType: 'video',
    durationLimit: 30,              
},
```